# LINQ to compare and excude/include different objects based on a similar type property

Tags: c#, linq

Take the following code

(pseudocode in the linq part --> lstApples.Except(i => i.id = Banana.ID);)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

delegate int NumberChanger(int n);

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Banana> lstBananas = new List<Banana>()
            {
                new Banana {IDBanana = 1, Name = "Mike", Surname = "x" },
                new Banana {IDBanana = 2, Name = "Mauro", Surname = "y" },
                new Banana {IDBanana = 3, Name = "Ciccio", Surname = "z" },
                new Banana {IDBanana = 4, Name = "Enzo", Surname = "w" }
            };

            List<Apple> lstApples = new List<Apple>()
            {
                new Apple {IDApple = 1, Brand = "Melinda", Type = "Golden" },
                new Apple {IDApple = 1, Brand = "Melinda", Type = "Tirolese" },
                new Apple {IDApple = 1, Brand = "Melinda", Type = "d" },
                new Apple {IDApple = 1, Brand = "Melinda", Type = "f" },
                new Apple {IDApple = 1, Brand = "Secure", Type = "r" },
                new Apple {IDApple = 1, Brand = "Melinda", Type = "g" },
                new Apple {IDApple = 1, Brand = "AllOver", Type = "Tirolese" },
                new Apple {IDApple = 1, Brand = "Valtellina", Type = "Rossa" },
                new Apple {IDApple = 1, Brand = "ThisOne", Type = "Verde" },
                new Apple {IDApple = 1, Brand = "Melinda", Type = "Blu" },
            };

            lstApples.Except(i => i.id = Banana.ID);
        }
    }


    public class Banana
    {
        public int IDBanana { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }

    public class Apple
    {
        public int IDApple { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need to filter out object on a list based on some other object property.

Example: When the apple id is the same as banana, cut out the apple from the list ** USING EXCEPT** mainly, or other ways if not possible

Linq make it cumbersome. How to do it?

Comment: First you have "=" instead of "==".  Usually when I'm comparing two arrays of equal length I use ."Where((x,i) =>" or "Select((x,i) =>" where x is the value and i is the index of the value.  So my code looks like lstBananas.Where((x,i) => x == lstApples[i])

Comment: It was some pseudocode..... why the = instead of == punctualization..... Gonna try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lstApples.Where(a=>!lstBananas.Any(b=>b.IDBanana == a.IDApple))
```

Or you can also do a `join`

Comment: I found this is retrieving the correct id's, but I have then to select them again from the list

lstApples.Select(apple => apple.IDApple)
    .Except(lstBananas.Select(banana => banana.IDBanana))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(result => Console.WriteLine(result.ToString())); 



Anyway yours is very good too!

Comment: Could you please explain me what linq is doing in your code???

I have not fully understood it....

I get that it compares the two lists by id, but I do not get how it manages to exclude the results from the main list